# Adminlte 3.1 second treeview, links disappearing upon collapsing main menu

Tags: html, jquery, css, treeview, adminlte

I'm using adminlte v3.1, and have a second treeview to show a document library.

I'm using the following HTML:
`<ul class="mt-2 flex-column nav nav-pills nav-sidebar nav-child-indent" data-widget="treeview" data-accordion="true" id="doc_menu">`

However, when collapsing the main menu, through a push action on the button, this also "collapses" the text of the links on the second menu.

`<a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button" data-enable-remember="true">`

How can I make sure that the push action of the show/hide menu only affects the main menu, and does not affect the second treeview on the site?